# how to plot multiple time series in the same graph with customized x axis

Tags: javascript, django, python-2.7, highcharts, time-series

I want to plot multiple time series in the same graph using the same xaxis witch a customized one. this is my code:
in views.py this is my function:

```
def cdr_weekly_comparison(request):
    #import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    acc = cdr_data.find()
    donnees=[]
    dt = datetime.now()
    y = dt.year
    m = dt.month
    d = dt.day
    for k in range(7):
        m = dt.month
        data=[]
        liste=[]
        liste_time=[]
        for i in acc:
            try:
                if (i['start_uepoch'].year==y and i['start_uepoch'].month== m and i['start_uepoch'].day==d-k):
                    liste.append([i['start_uepoch'],i['duration']])
            except:
                pass
        for q in range(24):
            for mnt in range(60):
                liste2=[]
                ACD=0
                somme_duration=0
                n=0
                for p in liste:
                    if (p[0].hour==q and p[0].minute == mnt):
                        liste2.append(p[1])
                        temps=p[0]
                if len(liste2)!=0:
                    for j in liste2:
                        somme_duration+=j
                        n+=1
                    ACD=round((float(somme_duration)/n)*100)/100
                    liste_time.append(calendar.timegm(temps.timetuple()))
                    data.append(ACD)
                else:
                    st=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(q*3600+mnt*60))
                    patern="%H:%M:%S"
                    time_now=datetime.strptime(st, patern)
                    time_now=time_now.replace(year=y, month=m, day=d-k)
                    liste_time.append(calendar.timegm(time_now.timetuple()))
                    data.append(0)
        donnees.append(data)

    MesVars={
    "d1": donnees[0],
    "d2": donnees[1],
    "d3": donnees[2],
    "d4": donnees[3],
    "d5": donnees[4],
    "d6": donnees[5],
    "d7": donnees[6],
    "tense": liste_time,
    }
    return render(request,"frontend/cdr_weekly_comparison.html",MesVars)
```

in cdr_weekly_comparison.html I have this

```
{% extends "frontend/master.html" %}
{% load i18n cdr_extras country_dialcode_tags common_tags %}
{% load cache %}
{% block extra_head %}
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({ autoHeight: false,  clearStyle: true  });
  });
  </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script>
 var d1={{d1}};
 var d2={{d2}};
 var d3={{d3}};
 var d4={{d4}};
 var d5={{d5}};
 var d6={{d6}};
 var d7={{d7}};
 var liste_time={{tense}};
</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<script id="source" language="javascript">
   (function selectOne() {
      var dataF={{num|safe}};
      var select = document.getElementById('mySelect');
          df = document.createDocumentFragment();
      for (var i=0; i<=dataF.length; i++) {
         var option = document.createElement('option');
         option.value = dataF[i];
         option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dataF[i]));
         df.appendChild(option);
               }
      select.appendChild(df);
    }());
</script>

<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'weekly comparison',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: null,
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            data : liste_time
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Average Call Duration'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
   //     tooltip: {
   //         valueSuffix: '°C'
   //     },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: ((new Date()).getDate()) + "-" + ((new Date()).getMonth()+1) + "-" +(new Date()).getFullYear(),
            data: d1
         }, {
            name: ((new Date()).getDate()-1) + "-" + ((new Date()).getMonth()+1) + "-" +(new Date()).getFullYear(),
            data: d2

        }, {
            name: ((new Date()).getDate()-2) + "-" + ((new Date()).getMonth()+1) + "-" +(new Date()).getFullYear(),
            data: d3
        }, {
              name: ((new Date()).getDate()-3) + "-" + ((new Date()).getMonth()+1) + "-" +(new Date()).getFullYear(),
            data: d4
        }, {
           name: ((new Date()).getDate()-4) + "-" + ((new Date()).getMonth()+1) + "-" +(new Date()).getFullYear(),
            data: d5
        }, {
           name: ((new Date()).getDate()-5) + "-" + ((new Date()).getMonth()+1) + "-" +(new Date()).getFullYear(),
            data: d6
        }, {
            name: ((new Date()).getDate()-6) + "-" + ((new Date()).getMonth()+1) + "-" +(new Date()).getFullYear(),
            data: d7

         }]
    });
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Unfortunately this codes doesn't give me the result I want it gives me this result: just the last day data is displayed and the xaxis doesn't show me the time from 00:00 to 23:00 with a step minute by minute.
[image: graph result]

The result wanted is 7 time series every line prensents the time serie of a day, so d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7 are successively the data of each day and the liste_time is times that I want to be shown in the xaxis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good case for the `pointStart` and `pointInterval` properties, on a `datetime` type x axis.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/92gkjwo3/

You can use the axis label `formatter` function, and the `tickInterval` properly to define the placement and format of the labels.

References:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointInterval
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointStart

Comment: this looks interesting I'll try it and tell you the result

Comment: for the xaxis it's ok but for the lines I still getting only the last day

Comment: have you tested the output of your d1 : d7 variables to see that they contain the expected data?

Comment: Looking at your chart image, it seems that the data for the other series is outputting all zeros.

Comment: That I can't answer. You'll need to go through your loops, and check your output at each point, until you find what's not flowing properly. Make sure the initial data that you pull is contains the appropriate values, and make sure you're not over-writing them somewhere

Comment: the problem is that when I test the code with some of my data online here http://codepad.org/OIlml4e3 I get the good result! so I think that the function should work correctly

Comment: I see all zeros in the output of that example still.

Comment: I solved it by putting the "acc=cdr_data.find()" after the first loop "for k inrange(7)" now I'm getting all plots.